# How to build the ssl with tomcat(clientauth="true") in linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, ssl

I tried a lot of time,but failed.could any one tell me step-by-step?can i only use tomcat and keytool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the process is a bit complicated, you need understand how Certification Authority(CA) and Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) works. steps

1. Create RootCA
2. Generate key pairs for tomcat server and clients
3. Generate CSR using step 2's keypair
4. Sign CSR with RootCA
5. Import CA reply
6. Install RootCA as trusted CA and Signed certificate in Server and clients machine.
7. Modify tomcat connector settings to use two-phase SSL

if you are not familiar with keytool or openssl command line, there are some GUI aviabile, e.g. [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/)  [TinaCA](http://tinyca.sm-zone.net/)
   And if you have windows server running, you can install certificate service and do the generate and sign stuff through web interface

Comment: if i use windows server to creat RootCA and ...how can i import those to tomcat?sorry for my poor english....

Comment: no need to import, download the signed certificate (PKCS#12) file to server and Tomcat supports pkcs12.

Comment: you mean there is only one file to copy?

Comment: To clarify, install RootCA as trusted CA and Signed certificate in Server,actually 2 files. keystoreFile="/xx/conf/XXX.p12" keystoreType="PKCS12" truststoreFile="/xx/conf/truststore.jks" truststoreType="JKS" clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS"  you can use .p12 file as keystoreFile, but you still need import rootCA into truststore

Comment: I use windows server 2003 as my server.It seems that the type of RootCA and Signed certificate are .cer.What should i do to copy that two files in .p12

Comment: I have install certificate service and do the generate and sign stuff through web interface.What should I do next?Also I exported a .pfx file and a .cer file.

Comment: Tomcat documentation covers everything you are asking. Go read it instead of asking on SO.

Comment: I don't know which part should I read.......